# Filtering elements of FeatureCollection using fusion table that contains list?

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter, list

I'm new to Google Earth Engine.

I am trying to filter all countries in the Americas from a Fusion Table that contains all countries in the World:

```
    // Load countries
    var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1tdSwUL7MVpOauSgRzqVTOwdfy17KDbw-1d9omPw')
```

This fusion table has a column named ISO3 with the code for each country but doesn't have a variable indicating region.

In addition, in GitHub I found a table that contains the ISO3 codes together with a variable for each region (Americas=19 in column "region-code"):

ISO-3166-Countries-with-Regional-Codes/all/all.csv

I don't know how to get this table directly into Google Earth Engine, but I can manually add it as a fusion table name ISO3_Americas containing 1 column "ISO3" with the list of all countries in the Americas:

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1_BoMJBCnMW72uy85jczMBHwH7lFe64M5_b_n6BSy

I would like to take the FeatureCollection "countries" and apply a filter: "keep if ISO3=any of the countries listed in ISO3_Americas"